# Need Help Parsing File for This Pattern "Feb 06 2010 15:49:00.017 MCO"

Tags: vb.net, regex

Need to parse a file for lines of data that start with this pattern "Feb 06 2010 15:49:00.017   MCO", where MCO could be any 3 letter ID, and return the entire record for the line.  I think I could get the first part, but the returning the rest of the line is where I get lost.

Here is some sample data.

> Feb 06 2010 15:49:00.017  MCO          -I  -I  -I  -I             0.34    527     0.26    0.24    184     Tentative   0.00    0           Radar Only       -RDR-                   -   -   -   -                                  No  282356N 0811758W         -      3-3
>   Feb 06 2010 15:49:00.017    MLB          -I  -I  -I  -I             44.31   3175    -10.05  -10.05  216     Established 0.00    0           Radar Only       -RDR-                   -   -   -   -                                  No  281336N 0812939W         -      2-
>   Feb 06 2010 15:49:00.018    MLB          -I  -I  -I  -I             44.31   3175    -10.05  -10.05  216     Established 15.51   99          Radar Only       -RDR-                   -   -   -   -                                  No  281336N 0812939W         -      2-
>   Feb 06 2010 15:49:00.023    QML     N856    7437-V   -I    62-V    61-V             67.00   3420    -30.93  15.34   534     Established 328.53  129         Reinforced       - -                     -   -   -   -                                  No  283900N 0815325W         -       -
>   Feb 06 2010 15:49:00.023    QML     N516SP  0723-V   -I    22-V    21-V             42.25   3460    -8.19   5.03    146     Established 243.93  83          Beacon Only      - -                     -   -   -   -                                  No  282844N 0812734W         -       -
>   Feb 06 2010 15:49:00.023    QML         2247-V   -I   145-V   144-V             78.88   3443    -39.68  23.68   676     Established 177.66  368         Reinforced       - -                     -   -   -   -                                  No  284719N 0820325W         -       -
>   Feb 06 2010 15:49:00.023    MLB         1200-V   -I    15-V    14-V             45.25   3015    -11.32  -20.97  475     Established 349.68  88          Beacon Only      - -                     -   -   -   -                                  No  280239N 0813104W         -       -
>   Feb 06 2010 15:49:00.023    MLB         1011-V   -I    91-V    90-V             94.50   3264    -56.77  10.21   698     Established 152.28  187         Beacon Only      - -                     -   -   -   -                                  No  283341N 0822244W         -       -
>            - -                     -   -   -   -

Comment: If you know the exact pattern that you need to match, then you don't really need to use regex. Why not just sub-string the relevant number of characters from the start of each line and compare to your desired string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like your date + 3 characters are always the first 5 fields (with space as delimiter). Just go through the file, and do a split on space to each line. Then get the first 5 fields

```
s=Split(strLineOfFile," ")
wscript.echo s(0),s(1),s(2),s(3),s(4)
```

No need regex

Answer (score 0):

From your sample data it seems that you don't have to check for the presence of a three letter identifier following the date -- it's always there. Add a final three letters to the regex if that's not a valid assumption. Also, add more grouping as needed for regex groups to be useful to you. Anyway:

```
import re
dtre = re.compile(r'^(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) [0-9]{2} [0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}')

[line for line in file if dtre.match(line)]
```

Wrap it in a `with` statement or whatever to open your file, then do any processing you need on the list this builds up.

Another possibility would be to use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension (replace the outer `[` and `]` with `(` and `)` to do so). This is useful if you're outputting results to somewhere as you go, the file is large and you don't need to have it all in memory for different purposes. Just be sure not to close the file before you consume the entire generator if you go with this approach!

Also, you could use `datetime`'s built-in parsing facility:

```
import datetime

for line in file:
    try:
        # the line[:24] bit assumes you're always going to have three-digit
        # µs part
        dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(line[:24], '%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
    except ValueError:
        # a ValueError means the beginning of the line isn't parseable as datetime
        continue
    # do something with the line; the datetime is already parsed and stored in dt
```

That's probably better if you're going to create the `datetime.datetime` object anyway.

Comment: The date will change all the time.  The format will remain the same.

Comment: Oh, I see. If you want to include lines with different `date` parts in your result set, I guess you do need a regex; will edit one in in a sec.

Comment: Well, there it is. I've also added a `datetime`-based approach which may be cleaner, though you'd have to spoil it a little if you needed to allow for variable-length µs parts (which is probably not a problem for you here, since you're dealing with a rigid logfile format).

Comment: BTW, look here: http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-behavior for docs on `datetime.datetime.strptime`.

Comment: I have this that traps the line, but I do not know how to get it to return the rest of the line.

([a-zA-Z]{3}\s\d\d\s\d\d\d\d\s\d\d:\d\d\\)

Comment: Have you tried my code from the answer? The list comprehension in the top code snippet should get you a list of all the lines matching your specification. Entire lines, not just initial fragments matching the regex. In general, if you're matching a regex against a string, it doesn't alter the string in any way, so you can still use it later. (If you successfully match a regex against the string bound to the variable `line`, this doesn't break `line` in any way, so you can still just return it / append it to some list / print it out / whatever.)